# Loading image at runtime in React native

Tags: android, react-native

There are many such situation in my app where I need to set image at run time. for example

**1. I get the Image URL on button click**

**2. I need to display image (loader) on button click**

**3. I need to change image depending upon the user's action**

How do I do this? So far I am not able to figure out how to access my nodes (let it be Text, Image,**Text Input** etc)

For showing loader image i found many packages, but i don't want to use a package just for showing a loader image.

Any code concept or tutorial will be Appreciated.

Update:
I am setting image in constructor (this is static image)
class LoginScreen extends Component {

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.setState({imageUri:'../images/loader.gif'});
}
```

In `render` method i'm using image tag like this

```
<Image source={{uri: this.state.imageUri}} style={styles.image}  />
```

It is throwing null error on the image tag
error: "null is not an object(evlauating this.state.imageUri).

Where Am i mistaking? Also i need to set this image on button click. Before that it should be hidden. How to implement these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

All of these cases can be resolved by using a component's state to store the image URLs. For instance:

```
<Image source={{uri: this.state.imageUri}} />
```

In your render method, followed by:

```
this.setState({
  imageUri: // Some uri...
})
```

Would allow you to have a dynamic image based on both user events, and runtime variables.

For showing a loading state while the image downloads I'd recommend the [react-native-image-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-image-progress) component which handles the display of a loading indicator while the image downloads.

Using a number of simple components like this is completely normal when developing React Native apps, so don't be overly-concerned about utilising 3rd-party code like that.

Comment: I'm using your code for setting state in constructor. Its throwing null pointer error on the line where i used <image> tag. Seems like this.setState({imageUri:'../images/loader.gif'}); didn't work in my code. I'm updating the question with my code. Please check if there is any issue

Comment: You need to read up on some [React Native fundamentals](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sample-application-movies.html) - `this.setState` isn't used within constructors, instead you should use `this.state = { ... }`

Comment: using this.state = { ... } the error goes but <Image source={{uri:this.state.imageUri}} style={styles.image}  /> still doesn't show the image. I'm confused with two coding styles of React Native. In one we use extend Component and in another we use react.createClasss. Both have different ways of coding and i always end up mixing them. May be here too. Can you help on why it is not showing image now?